# MySQL Remote Connection Cannot Find Specific Hosts

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I Have made a Desktop application with VB.Net & MySQL to run on a local network, my first computer which have the MySql Database installed is windows 10, MySQL is installed as a server machine I made a user with all privileges on the selected database and '%' access host.
connection string on main computer is Localhost, Root, Password, Database
connection string on terminal computers is 192.168.33.1 For Host, NTT As the user 'I have created', Password, Database,Port.

When I run the application on the terminal computers I got a message box with "Unable to find MySQL Specific Hosts'.

Any Solution Please,

Best Regards

Comment: can you access this server from your localhost?

Comment: yes when I run the application in the main machine it works perfectly

Comment: what if you type the ip 192.168.33.1 in windows explorer, are you see the machine?

Comment: I did not install a web server I have installed MySQL only so that internet explorer will show error but I have shared a folder on the network to check if there is any problem in the connection and the shared folder had appeared in all terminal computers

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these:

- Check your windows firewall to allow communications over `mysql default port: 3306`.
- Try to make a connection string using special `127.0.0.1` iploopback to test connectionstring on local host and if it works fine locally use same connectionstring except changing ip address to `192.168.33.1` on remote computer.